# Why does my child function require a 'return' statement to avoid erroring out? The parent function has no 'return' and no error

Tags: javascript

```
var a = function(param1) {
    var b = function(param2) {
        console.log(param1 + param2);
    }; 
    return b;
};

a(4)(5); // this logs "9"
```

Is the return statement (in this case "return b") always necessary? Why do we need it for one function here, but not the other? When is it necessary, and why?

Comment: `return` returns a value from the function. To understand how it works pretend you're a JS interpreter and interpret your code statement by statement.

Comment: What are you trying to do or understand?

Answer (score 2):

The expression

```
a(4)(5)
```

first calls function `a` with parameter `4` (`a(4)`), which returns `b` (which is a function). This returned function is then called with parameter `5`. It is the same as if you did

```
c = a(4); 
c(5);
```

So, you need the outer function `a` to return a function - because you treat it's result as a function. And you don't care if the inner function `b` returns anything as you don't use the result, so it doesn't matter if it returns anything.

Comment: Super helpful. Thanks for taking the time to explain this, totally makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The last line `a(4)(5);` calls `a` as a function (with input of `4`) and then immediately calls the result of `a` as a function (with input of `5`).  As you have it now, `a` returns a function `b`, so that works just fine.

Without trying it, I'm going to guess that commenting out the last `return` statement results in a "undefined is not a function error" or similar. In the absence of a `return` statement, the result of a function is `undefined`. So the attempt to call the result of `a` as a function fails.

Comment: That makes all the sense in the world. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

> Is the return statement (in this case "return b") always necessary?

A return statement isn't always necessary. However, in this case the expression:

```
a(4)(5)
```

requires `a(4)` to return a function that can be called with `(5)`. Consider:

```
var x = a(4);
x(5);
```

> Why do we need it for one function here, but not the other?

By default, functions return the value *undefined*. If you want a function to return some other value, you must use a return statement. In this case, `a` needs to return a function, it needs a return statement to do that.

Note that `b` also has a closure to *param1* so that the expression `param1 + param2` works as you expect.

> When is it necessary, and why?

It's necessary whenever you want a function to return some value other than *undefined*.

Comment: Hey, as you might have guessed I am pretty new to this. Reading all the comments here several times was helpful - this was actually the one that finally made it click. Thank you!

Comment: Cool, keep asking questions. :-)